# Hooking up more than 32 PCA9685s

Tags: pwm

https://learn.adafruit.com/16-channel-pwm-servo-driver/chaining-drivers

The above link says that we can daisy chain up to 62 of these boards together, but once we scroll down below, we see that we have to solder the offset pins for the i2c controller, and there are only 5 bits in that. That must mean that we can connect only controllers 0x40 through 0x71... Right?
But that configuration only allows us to connect 32 of these, how do i add more?

Also, In the future, i may need to add more than 62, so can i daisy chain another 62, and connect it to 2 other analog input pins in my microcontroller?

Comment: I see 6 bits: A0 to A5 makes 6 total.

Comment: @Mast They say a picture is worth a thousand words... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, should be 64. However, reading the datasheet:

> There are a maximum of 64 possible programmable addresses using the 6 hardware address pins.

It's 6, not 5!

> Two of these addresses, Software Reset and LED All Call, cannot be used
> because their default power-up state is ON, leaving a maximum of 62 addresses.

Hint: always refer to the official [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9685.pdf) of the device used, instead of guides built upon it, if confused about the properties of some device. There's only one official source: the datasheet.

An I²C with 62 devices might already be pretty heavily loaded. So, adding more is probably not a good idea, anyways, even if you *could* have more addresses.

I²C *bus muxes* solve the addressing problem: you have a device that acts as "switch" between multiple sub-busses. First you address that IC, switch to the right sub-bus, then you can talk to the I²C devices on that bus.

In your use case (thanks, @Maple), you could simply extend the I²C bus by compensating the loading by using active pull-up elements, or a bus repeater IC. See the comments.

Also, I don't know your host, but many things have multiple independent I²C buses, so you can have more than one 62-controller string to begin with.

And frankly, 62 16-channel drivers: that's already 992 channels. At some point you're reaching a complexity (and cost¹) where you can't buy Adafruit modules and "wire them up", cool as they are, but need to design your own board to hold your 62 PCA6985 - especially here, because the way you route the I²C lines greatly influences the loading of them.

I'd probably start by dividing that problem down to smaller problems, rather than trying to solve it all on one I²C bus.

---

¹ that adafruit board is ca. USD15. That's USD 15 × 62 = USD 930 for 62 devices. *Are you sure* your design is affordable? The IC alone, in the quantities you want, costs ca. two dollars.  Also, still pretty much the wrong device for your choice: you have vibration motors to control.

---

also, if this is still about the vibration motors from your last question: people asked you to specify how much current these will draw *for good reason*. You haven't answered that. But I can well imagine a motor drawing more than 30 mA, so you can't use it directly with this driver anyway. And you need flyback diodes...

Comment: "It's 6, not 5!" Didn't even need to look at the datasheet. There's a bloody great picture in the link.

Comment: Thumbs up for that.

Comment: Using muxes to solve bus loading is really bad idea when address space is not an issue. That is what bus buffers/repeaters are for, like [TC9517](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9517.pdf) for example. Even simple active pull-up like [LTC4311](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4311fa.pdf) is sufficient in most cases.

Comment: @Maple in this case, address space is a limiting factor, though.

Comment: Huh? 62 of these boards need only 62 addresses and support up to 992 servos. Where is the address limit? And most likely OP would be able to add another chain for same amount as soon as he/she understands that they are not connected to "analog input pins", but to one of the two Arduino Uno I2C ports.

Comment: @Maple ah darn, I was mixing OP's 32-device confusion with the actual 62-device bus.

Comment: @Maple tried to salvage what there is to salvage.

Comment: Frankly, I believe this is un-salvageable on the OP side for the whole different reason. Even with fast bus mode the sheer volume of data to be transmitted to set up duty for each motor means the latency in the system will make any kind of synchronization between the motors pretty much impossible.

Comment: @Maple but that's basically an approach problem of OP; I'm just as confused as you probably are how controlling several hundred vibration actuators is of any haptic benefit, or how this is planned to work out electromechanically, or power suppy-wise, should they operate simultaneously, or how >40 driver boards are fun to carry around or...

Comment: LMAO, I forgot that the count starts from 0. I'm so sorry for that. And no, this isn't about that previous question. I've just started learning about electronics, and arduino, coming from coding, and i was just curious.